# What do I need to put before the ampersand?

Tags: c, pointers, arguments, ampersand

Getting the following error for the argument line of extractMin:

randmst.c:129: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token

Let me know if I didn't paste enough code for the error to be obvious.

```
//the heap functions

//based on p. 163 of clrs
VertexPointer
extractMin(VertexPointer *heap, int &heap_size){
    VertexPointer max = heap[0];
    (*heap[0]).key = 100;
    heap_size = heap_size - 1;
    minHeapify(heap, heap_size, 1);
    return max;
}
```

Comment: There is no reference in C.

Comment: & token denotes the address of a variable, the function parameters should be changed to *heap_size [that implies it holds the address of a variable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this `extractMin(VertexPointer *heap, int &heap_size)` in `C` - change it to `extractMin(VertexPointer *heap, int *heap_size)`

There is no Pass-by-reference in C. So you should have something like this:

```
extractMin(VertexPointer *heap, int *heap_size){
    VertexPointer max = heap[0];
    (*heap[0]).key = 100;
    *heap_size = *heap_size - 1;
    minHeapify(heap, *heap_size, 1); 
    return max;
}
```

The `&` is used to get the address of the variable so when calling the function you should call it this way:

```
extractMin(someAddress_to_heap, someAddress_to_heap_size)
```

Comment: beautiful.  make sure you note that he's dereferencing `heap_size` within the function.  When you call `extractMin`, you'll have to apply the `&` address-of operator to the `heap_size` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Passing by refrence doesnt work in C, there is a difference in passing by refrence and passing by address. C++ support passing by refrence but C doesnt.
Change your code to

```
VertexPointer
extractMin(VertexPointer *heap, int *heap_size)
```